# Normal http request in jquery without xhr header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to send a ajax-like request with these headers(or something like this):

```
GET example.com/ajaxapi/article/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Accept: application/hal+json
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The important point is doing this without **X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest** in headers.

$.ajax(), $.get(),... all add a default xhr header to this.

Comment: Just use XMLHttpRequest directly.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why down vote this. I found a solution to this. Something's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the headers with the beforeSend function wich is a property of the settings object of the ajax method.

From the [documentation](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.ajax), the description of beforeSend :

> A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent. **Use this to set custom headers**, etc. The jqXHR and settings objects are passed as arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the request. As of jQuery 1.5, the beforeSend option will be called regardless of the type of request.

Example :

```
$.ajax('/yoururl', {
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        // stuff goes here
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question if it helps someone else.

```
$.ajax({
    url:   url,
    crossDomain: true
});
```

crossDomain option did the trick and removed XMLHttpRequest header.